# If you have a set of eigenvectors with full multiplicity, is it always possible to orthogonalize them?

Tags: linear-algebra

a)  construct a (diagonalizable) 2×2 complex symmetric matrix not admitting an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors

b)  construct a 2×2 complex symmetric matrix which cannot be diagonalized

The point of this exercise is to show that theorems that works for self adjoint or symmetric real matrices do not work for complex symmetric matrices. I had no problem with part b but I don't understand part a. If we have a diagonalizable complex symmetric matrix, that means we have a full set of eigenvalues with full geometric multiplicity otherwise, we wouldn't be able to diagonalize it. If that is the case, then we also have a full set of eigenvectors. We can just apply gram-schmidt and get a set of orthonormal vectors. The only way part a can be true is if Gram-schmidt doesn't work. Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

It is often easier to try rank-one matrices first.

Part (b) is easy. Just pick a nonzero vector $u$ such that $u^Tu$ (note: not $u^\ast u$) is equal to zero. Then $uu^T$ is complex symmetric (this should be obvious) but not diagonalisable (do you see why?).

For part (a), find a pair of vectors $u$ and $v$ such that both $u^Tu$ and $u^\ast v$ are nonzero but $u^Tv=0$. Then the matrix $A=uu^T$ will do the trick because $u$ and $v$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to two different eigenvalues but they are not orthogonal to each other.

Now, to answer your question:

> If we have a diagonalizable complex symmetric matrix, that means we have a full set of eigenvalues with full geometric multiplicity otherwise, we wouldn't be able to diagonalize it. If that is the case, then we also have a full set of eigenvectors.

You are correct at this point.

> We can just apply gram-schmidt and get a set of orthonormal vectors. The only way part a can be true is if Gram-schmidt doesn't work. Why would that be the case?

You always get an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb C^n$ by performing Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation on an eigenbasis. However, the outcome is not necessarily an **eigen**basis, and we haven't any reason to expect that it is.

Comment: for part a) did you meant to say A=uv^t or vu^t? There should be a v involved right?

Comment: @William $A$ is $uu^T$. There isn't any typo.